# Calling function inside a function -JS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

So I am calling a function inside another function but for some reason it doesn't work. The function is never called.

```
save : function(component) { 
    var maxFileSize = 750000;
    var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement(); 
    var file = fileInput.files[0];  
            if (file.size > maxFileSize) {
        alert('File size cannot exceed ' + maxFileSize + ' bytes.\n' +
              'Selected file size: ' + file.size);
        return;
    }
 var fr = new FileReader();
 var self=this;
 fr.onload = function() {
        var fileContents = fr.result;
        var base64Mark = 'base64,';
        var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64Mark) + base64Mark.length;
        fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
        alert("WORKING"); //check at this point- alert works
        self.upload(component, file, fileContents);
        alert("DID IT WORK?"); // This alert not shown so upload call not working
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file); //fr.onload function triggered from here
},

upload: function(component, file, fileContents)
{ alert("Here");  //NEVER CALLED              
}
```

I've updated my code and for some reason it still does not work. I've added 'var self = this;'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` pointer is different inside the callback function. So, you need to save it into a different variable. Then, use that variable instead of `this` inside your callback. For a Lightning helper, I save it to one called `helper`

```
save : function(component) { 
    var maxFileSize = 750000;
    var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement(); 
    var file = fileInput.files[0];  
            if (file.size > maxFileSize) {
        alert('File size cannot exceed ' + maxFileSize + ' bytes.\n' +
              'Selected file size: ' + file.size);
        return;
    }

 var fr = new FileReader();
 var helper = this;
 fr.onload = function() {
        var fileContents = fr.result;
        var base64Mark = 'base64,';
        var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64Mark) + base64Mark.length;
        fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
        alert("WORKING"); //check at this point- alert works
        helper.upload(component, file, fileContents);
        alert("DID IT WORK?"); // This alert not shown so upload call not working
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file); //fr.onload function triggered from here
},

upload: function(component, file, fileContents)
{ alert("Here");  //NEVER CALLED              
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: So use upload.call(..);?

Comment: No, just store the reference to this as something else, then use that to call the function on the helper. The problem is that your onload function is being called by the FileReader, so you can't control what it decides to do with the "this" reference. So, keep track of the helper with your own var.

Comment: No worries, there's a good reference on MDN somewhere where they talk about "this" and "that" and explain all this well. I can't find it though, because this and that are rubbish search terms for google!

Comment: I can imagine haha

Comment: @Aiden I have updated my code to include 'var self = this;' but it still is not going the my upload function. Any ideas?

Comment: The variable "file" is used in "helper.upload(component, file, fileContents)", but it is not defined anywhere. When I've done file upload before, I loop through the files in my controller and then pass them one-by-one to the helper. So my save function is takes file as a parameter e.g. save : function(component, file) {

Comment: @Aiden I have added the rest of the code. Everything is defined but its just the upload call that's the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66200/discussion-between-aidan-and-m-guy).